# Автоматизированное пополнение фонемного словаря

Tags: java, c#, распознавание-речи

Хочу автоматизировать пополнение фонемного словаря.

Кратко: есть база русских слов и программа распознавания речи, которая понимает фонемы этих слов. Пример ручного заполнения: эфир  `e ff ii r`, язык  `j i z yy k` (программа на C#).

Или, может быть, лучше сделать отдельное приложение, работающее со словарём уже на Java? Обращаюсь за помощью. Спасибо!

Comment: в чем заключается вопрос?

Comment: Написать программу, которая будет переводить введенное слова в фонемы. Как будто это переводчик.

Comment: Возможно ли это сделать?